# Trouble with json parsing for windows phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, json-deserialization

```
  {
   "code": 0,
   "message": "success",
   "expense": {
           "account_name": "Printing and Stationery",
           "paid_through_account_name": "Petty Cash"
              }
  }
```

This is my json format,
And i'm try to deserialize it with the following class

```
   [DataContract]
public class Expenses
{

    [DataMember(Name = "code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "expense")]
    public Expense Expense { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Expense
{
    [DataMember(Name = "account_name")]
    public string Account_Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "paid_through_account_name")]
    public int Paid_Through_Account_Name { get; set; }
}
```

and i call this class with the help of the follwing code

```
     var myObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Expenses>(json);
```

but while executing the above line i always get an error stating that,

```
     An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in     PhoneApp18.DLL but was not handled in user code

 If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

help me to get out of this issue....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `json`   "paid_through_account_name": "Petty Cash" where "Petty Cash" is `string`. But in your model property public  `Paid_Through_Account_Name` has type `int`. Try change type to `string`.

```
[DataContract]
public class Expense
{
    [DataMember(Name = "account_name")]
    public string Account_Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "paid_through_account_name")]
    public string Paid_Through_Account_Name { get; set; } //string type
}
```

**Update**

Probably you are trying to update the UI from the other (not main) thread. In Windows Phone app you can update `UI` **only in main thread**. In this case, use such construction Dispatcher.

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                          TextBox.Text = myString;
                    });
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx

http://weimenglee.blogspot.ru/2013/07/windows-phone-tip-updating-ui-from.html

Comment: when i try to put the content in a **TextBox** I get an error stating that 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException': Invalid cross thread access.  What should i do to rectify this??